# How to Exclude few specs from running from Cypress run command but should be able to run via import command from other spec

Tags: cypress, cypress-configuration

How to exclude certain specs to be run in the folder when **npx cypress run** is executed
for example please see the image

I don't want to execute my spec which is in **Marketing/Sales/sc1111.spec.ts** but at the same time I want it to execute via the import statement mentioned in **Finance/Verify/sc1111-main.spec.ts**

is there anything that I can do in the folder level itself to stop it from running
asking this as I have 100's of folders that are going to be like this and I don't want to mess up the configuration file with excluding list so Please help me regarding this with your suggestions
[image]

Comment: You could alter the file names of the other files so runs will not pick them up. Why have you chosen this way to write your tests?

Comment: @jjhelguero thank you i will try that way 
the intent was to have the specs in those areas  where it belongs as my main spec will run into those areas so i wanted to keep that area related code in that folder and call all of this in one place via main spec

Comment: That seems like more of an organizing desire than a functional. You might want to check if performance will take a hit with that approach.

Answer (score 2):

There is a configuration option to exclude files

[Configuration - e2e](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#e2e)

> **excludeSpecPattern**
> A String or Array of glob patterns used to ignore test files that would otherwise be shown in your list of tests.

---

#### Minimal reproducible example

If I set up a simple project with three spec files

[image]

then add `test-b.cy.js` to the exclude pattern

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    excludeSpecPattern: 'cypress/e2e/test-b.cy.js'
  },
})
```

when I execute `yarn cypress run`, test-b.cy.js isn't run.

[image]